# mysqldump to csv in utf8

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8, debian, export-to-csv

I'm using the following command to export data from my database to csv:

```
mysqldump -u root -p -T/home/xxx/stock_dump -t --fields-terminated-by=";" products stock
```

But the database is in UTF-8 and this command exports UTF-8 characters incorrectly, e.g.

`ŻYWIEC ZDRÓJ` is `ĂÂťYWIEC ZDRĂâJ`

How do I export it in the correct UTF-8 format?

Adding `--default-character-set=utf8` did not help at all.

Or if it is not possible, how do I postprocess it the easiest way? Can iconv do anything about it?

Comment: is your file maybe not displayed as utf8? does it have a BOM?

Comment: Are you sure the exported file is not in UTF8 format? What if it is, but the way you're reading it is interpreting it as something else? Encoding issues like this are annoying because each time you view the data it's *interpreted* and may be interpreted incorrectly. If you have that text in a known-good format, you can always check for encoding inconsistencies.

Comment: I'm sure it is invalid because when I generate it by PHP it has totally different characters and does display correctly

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` [produces UTF-8 encoded dumps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_default-character-set) unless told otherwise (or unless you use a really, *really* old version of `mysqldump` -- anyways, your correct using of `--default-character-set=utf8` settles it).

Either your text editor is not recognizing UTF-8 correctly, or the data in the database is already wrongly encoded.

Comment: It is possible that data in database was put into UTF8 table via Latin1 connection. But when I use PHP or mysql client it displays values correctly. Not sure how do I really check it out.